# Shared Google Calendar Permissions are Changing Somehow

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

**Background:**
My organization creates and maintains one "primary" Google Calendar for each building using www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/... API calls.

Each of these primary calendars have two accounts with role="owner" and type="user" which we manage manually (only developers are aware of the owner accounts).

Through our app, we maintain a list of accounts with role="writer" and type="user", and each calendar has one role="reader" with type="default" (so by default, anyone can read from the calendar but only a few people can write).

We expose the ability for some administrators to change the role of their building's users to add or delete "writer" permissions.

Users can add this calendar to their list of calendars in order to view any of the building's events on "their own" calendar.

**Problem:**
Somehow, on very very rare occasion, a building's primary calendar manages to no longer be shared publicly. The role="reader" with type="default" seems to be gone. I am at a complete loss as to how this is happening. I can not rule out the possibility of a malicious user or a mistake in our code.

**Question:**
Oh wise wizards of the internet, what are all the things I should look for in order to nail down and/or fix this occasional loss of public default access? What further questions shall I ask for better results?

Thank you for sharing your magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only admins have edit rights to all calendars in the domain. For more info on how calendar sharing works, see [Super administrators](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60765?hl=en). This will help you to have more security in your domain.

You can also check the "History" of your Google Calendar as a G Suite administrator, you can track changes to calendars, events, and subscriptions in the [Google Calendar audit](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6110475?hl=en).

> **Note**: Calendar audit log entries show only up to the past six months
>   of data. Support will not have access to information outside that time
>   frame.

And if you wanted to check the history of account changes of a particular google account, see this [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2949085?hl=en).

> **Note**: Change History maintains a record of activities for the last two years